# How to enable VT-X to adjust the processor of a vm

Tags: virtualbox, multi-core

I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox. I've been trying to adjust the process of my Virtual Machine but the slider of the Processor on the Processor tab is disabled. As far as I know, VT-x should be enabled on the Acceleration tab, but the problem is that tab is also disabled. I tried to enable 3D acceleration on Display, but the process just improved a little. There is also an issue on adjusting the Base Memory of the VM such as it only considers upto 3175 mb.

Upon checking BIOs, Virtualization Technology is already enabled.

This is the spec of my HOST machine:

Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU     E5620   @   2.40GHz (16CPUs)

This [is the snapshot of the VM's settings](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0AqcKgEkHoRTnR3OWk5cURod28/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What version VirtualBox are you using?

Comment: Version 4.1.8 r75467

Comment: Please add Host OS (architecture, version) and guest OS (architecture, version). From your screenshot, and from your comment below we do not have any indication that your question is related to Ubuntu.

Comment: Check the security options in your BIOS, maybe one of them is the culprit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend upgrading your VirtualBox to the latest.  I'm running 3.2.12, and I can change the settings.

Also you may want to check to see if there is a BIOS update to your system.

[image]

[image]

Comment: My version is updated, and one thing is that I have no option to choose Windows 7(64bit) when creating new. I am sure that VT-x is enabled while Hyper-V is disabled.

Comment: It looks like you may have other problems.  See [Image](http://ubuntuone.com/5gL9OEgb1EPqV1dJ9KnaaD), it shows Windows 7 64bit as an option.  I would suggest removing and re-installing VirtualBox.

Comment: I already re install the VirtualBox. I am not sure what's the problem...

Comment: At this point I would really recommend that you file a bug report with [VirtualBox Support](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker).  Sorry I couldn't be of more assistant.

Comment: Thanks btw. I upgraded it upto the latest version but not luck. Then I just uninstalled it and installed version 4.2.6 and it worked! I think upgrading the version with its extension pack also disabled the VT-x, just no idea why.